# Identifier expected after this token Error

Tags: java

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread() {
    public void run() {

    }
};

Thread thread2 = new Thread() {
    public void run() {

    }
};

thread1.start();
thread2.start();
```

How can I get rid out of this error? In the line thread1.start() and thread2.start() I get the same error -> Syntax Error on token start, Identifier expected after this token.

Comment: Above code seems to be completely valid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Syntax Error on token start, Identifier expected after this token.

means that you declared these statements:

```
thread1.start();
thread2.start();
```

as members of the class.
But these are not valid member declarations.

These don't create any issue as  these are valid declarations :

```
Thread thread1 = new Thread() {
    public void run() {

    }
};

Thread thread2 = new Thread() {
    public void run() {

    }
};
```

As alternative, you could move the `start()` invocation statements in an initializer or a method.
Here is a example with an initializer :

```
public class Foo {

    Thread thread1 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {

        }
    };

    Thread thread2 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {

        }
    };

    {
      thread1.start();
      thread2.start();
    }

}
```

Or if it makes more sense, you can also change the fields into local variables and declare the whole statements in a method :

```
public class Foo {

    public void myMethod(){    

       Thread thread1 = new Thread() {
          public void run() {

          }
       };

       Thread thread2 = new Thread() {
         public void run() {

        }
       };

       thread1.start();
       thread2.start();
    }

}
```

Comment: You are welcome :) The next time, don't hesitate to post the class declaration, it may ease the problem solving.

Answer (score 1):

Put it inside the main method. It will work properly if you put it inside

```
public static void main(String args[]){
   //your code
}
```